# JPA 2 merge is inserting instead of updating when primary key is UUID

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, jpa-2.0

For one of my entities I want to use UUID as primary key instead of a Long. The entity extends AbstractEntityUUID:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntityUUID implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 40076842287035126L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (getId() != null) {
            return getId().hashCode();
        }
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        AbstractEntityUUID other = (AbstractEntityUUID) obj;
        if (getId() == null || other.getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!getId().equals(other.getId())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The entity itself is:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "schemaName", name = "order")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Order extends AbstractEntityUUID {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6358231835578038565L;

    @Column(precision = 10, scale = 2)
    protected BigDecimal itemPrice;

    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @Basic(fetch = LAZY)
    protected Date purchaseDate;

    // other properties and getters & setters ...

}
```

The persist method works fine:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.setItemPrice(BigDecimal.ONE);
order = getEM().persist(order);
```

A new row is created on the database table with the correct info. When there is a merge later on is when the issue occurs:

```
order.setPurchaseDate(new Date());
order = getEM().merge(order);
```

The previous row seems to be left unchanged and a new one is created with a new primary key which includes the price and date.

When the primary key is Long with GenerationType.IDENTITY the row is updated correctly instead and it works as expected.

This is run on a WildFly 16 server on an ejb 3 bean. The Hibernate implementation seems to be 5.3.9. The DB is MySQL server 5.7.

It is fine if Java generates the UUID values and I would rather not change that unless it is required to make the entity work with a UUID as primary key.

Comment: In this case, if entity is in persistent state after .persist or .find you don't need to call merge. Hibernate will flush the changes when transaction is ready to be committed. But I am not sure why it is not working as expected in your code.

Comment: @arseniyandru This is correct. But in this same use case, when the entity has a Long as PK it works as expected. This only happens when the PK is an UUID implemented as described.

Comment: It's not clear when the id is actually generated. Are you generating the UUID in your code (not shown)? If you rely on hibernate to generate the UUID, I'd expect annotations to be more like `@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")`

Comment: @Cascader I already have the annotation javax.persistence.GeneratedValue and it seems I cannot add the additional property generator = "uuid" for it. The GenericGenerator is Hibernate specific and I am trying to make this work with JPA only for now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that persist is working as expected when MySql generates the UUID? Is the id of the entity the same as the id inserted into the database?

Comment: This seems to be another interesting find. After persist, when I do an entityManager.find(entityClass, id) it does not return anything even though the row is created in MySQL. When I do a query for another property which is unique to that row I receive the entity and they have the same id (tested with equals). It seems that the default entityManager.find(...) method to find by IDs does not function well for UUIDs or a possible bug.

Comment: You are right, UUID as ID in combination with MySQL doesn't work. Entity is persisted (assert entity.id is not null) but find by entiy.id returns null. Reproduced with JPA 2.2, HBN 5.3.10 and MySQL 5.7.26. BTW: Same setup with H2 works fine.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this on your end. UUIDs in JPA have been around for quite some time. If I don't find a solution to this soon I will file a bug report with Hibernate.

Comment: One more note, in my setup HBN creates the schema and chooses binary as data type for the ID column.

Comment: Same for me. It creates a BINARY(255) for the PK in MySQL.